# scroll view slides back to original point without staying there

Tags: iphone

i have a view on which i have image view and scroll view and tableview . scroll view is double the iphone screen .now when i slide the scroll to left i does not stand there rather it slides back to starting position ,how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrollview should not be off screen, and not bigger than the screen. You set the scrollviews contentsize to be bigger than the scrollview itself..

Comment: whats the meaning of scrool view if its equal to screen

Comment: Larasronen is correct - you set the scroll view to at most the size of the screen and use the content size property to set the size of the data it holds. e.g. [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, totalHeight)]; where totalHeight can be > than size of screen